# PHP: Multiple SQL Statements

Tags: php, sql, oracle

I have a SQL query which looks like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM TABLE ... 
INSERT ...
DELETE ...";
```

and I want to use multiple statements when querying the Oracle database. I know in mySQL there is mysqli_multi_query(). Is this possible in Oracle?

Thank you.

Comment: did you try making a begin..end block?

Answer (score 0):

Taken from: [Using PHP and Oracle Database 12c Implicit Result Sets](https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/entry/using_php_oci8_2_0)

The new Oracle Database 12c "Implicit Result Sets" (IRS) feature allows query results to be returned from a stored PL/SQL procedure (or a PL/SQL anonymous block) without requiring special PHP code. Support for IRS is available in PHP's OCI8 2.0.0-devel extension when it is compiled and used with Oracle Database 12c. (OCI8 2.0 can be compiled and used with other versions of Oracle Database but the available feature set is reduced).

```
<?php
$c = oci_connect('hr', 'welcome', 'localhost/pdborcl');
$sql =
 "declare
    c1 sys_refcursor;
  begin
    open c1 for select city from locations where rownum < 4;
    dbms_sql.return_result(c1);
    open c1 for select first_name, last_name from employees where rownum < 4;
    dbms_sql.return_result(c1);
  end;";
$s = oci_parse($c, $sql);
oci_execute($s);
while (($s2 = oci_get_implicit_resultset($s))) {
    // Now treat $s2 as a distinct query statement resource
    $ncols = oci_num_fields($s2);
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $ncols; ++$i) {
        $colname = oci_field_name($s2, $i);
        echo $colname . " ";
    }
    echo "\n";
    while (($row = oci_fetch_row($s2)) != false) {
        foreach ($row as $item) {
            echo $item . " ";
        }
        echo "\n";
    }
}
?>
```

Alternatively you can create a stored procedure in Oracle (which can contain multiple statements and output parameters) and then call it from PHP.